# jQuery basic help

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm sure I'm going to lose some rep points for this, because it's such a basic question, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with jQuery selectors using "#"  to select by id.

given this element in my document:

```
<%= Html.CheckBox("IsAlwaysValid", true,
                    new { onchange = "showHideValidSetList()", id = "IsAlwaysValidCheckBox" })%>
```

(which outputs the following markup:

```
<input checked="checked" id="IsAlwaysValidCheckBox" name="IsAlwaysValid" onchange="showHideValidSetList()" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="IsAlwaysValid" type="hidden" value="false" />
```

)

Then this function using a jQuery selector:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHideValidSetList() {
        if ($("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").checked) {
            alert("IsAlwaysValidCheckBox is checked");
            return;
        }
        else {
            alert("IsAlwaysValidCheckBox is NOT checked");
            return;
        }
    }
</script>
```

should be exactly equivalent to this one using the javascript DOM:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHideValidSetList() {
        if (document.getElementById("IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").checked) {
            alert("IsAlwaysValidCheckBox is checked");
            return;
        }
        else {
            alert("IsAlwaysValidCheckBox is NOT checked");
            return;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Right?  But the javascript version works as expected, while the jQuery one always takes the "else" branch, showing that it's not really looking at the state of the checkbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: fyi, we don't downvote "stupid" questions; there are none. we might downvote duplicates though ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
if ($(checkBoxControl).attr("checked")) {
```

instead of this:

```
if ($("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").checked) {
```

Though it looks like jQuery selectors return DOM elements (like checkboxes), they really return a jQuery object, which does not have a method called `checked`. You can see this most clearly in the uncompressed jquery source code (from [the current release, version 1.3.2](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)):

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    init: function( selector, context ) {
        // ...
        // Handle $(DOMElement)
        if ( selector.nodeType ) {
             this[0] = selector;
             this.length = 1;
             this.context = selector;
             return this;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

Many of the interesting jQuery methods (like animate, attr, html, etc.) operate on `this.context`, which is specified or redefined whenever you apply a selector.

Comment: Thanks, Jeff (and everyone else that responded).  I didn't understand the distinction between returning a jQuery object and returning the selected element.

Comment: My pleasure - I love jQuery, but it wouldn't kill them to explain this idiom in the core documentation. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").checked
```

is incorrect as `$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox")` returns the jQuery object, not the element. The jQuery object has no property called `checked` which is why it is entering the `else`.

you want:

```
$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").val()
```

or:

```
$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox:checked").length > 0
```

or:

```
$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").attr("checked") === "checked"
```

or:

```
$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox")[0].checked
```

or:

```
$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").get(0).checked
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using

```
if ($("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").attr("checked")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use this:

```
$("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").attr("checked")
```

to determine whether the checkbox is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to do a simple thing:

`$('#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox:checked').length`

The selector:checked is jquery specific to return a checked element. The length checks if there are any elements returned.

Many ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showHideValidSetList() {
        if ($("#IsAlwaysValidCheckBox").val()) {
            alert("IsAlwaysValidCheckBox is checked");
            return;
        }
        else {
            alert("IsAlwaysValidCheckBox is NOT checked");
            return;
        }
    }
</script>
```

the [val](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/val) method is sort of a "cross-element" way of checking the value ... whether it's a textbox, select list, or checkbox ... you can use .val() to get/set the value of it :-)